# Buffered Writer in Java not writing correctly

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

Im making a madlib program that opens a txt file then asks the user for data then presents a final madlib it shows up perfectly in the console but only the last line of the madlib appears in the text file please help this in Java btw.

```
FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(name + ".txt");
BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(outFile);

long start = System.nanoTime();    
content = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a/n " + 
       m.group().subSequence(1,m.group().length()-1));

madlib = m.replaceFirst(content);
System.out.println(madlib);
bf.write(madlib);

long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
elapsedTime=elapsedTime/1000000;
System.out.println(m.group().subSequence(1,m.group().length()-1) + " ; " + 
       content + " ; " + elapsedTime +"ms");
bf.write(m.group().subSequence(1,m.group().length()-1) + " ; " + content + 
       " ; " + elapsedTime +"ms");
bf.close();
```

Comment: The `BufferedWriter` is writing correctly. Your logic is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your code is nested inside of while loop, especially given your use of `m.group()`, and if so, you've got too much inside of the loop since you're creating a new BufferedWriter each time the loop loops, and thus over-writing all that was written previously.

Solution: Create your BufferedWriter *before* the loop, write with it, *inside* of the loop, and close it *after* the loop ends.  Something like (pseudocode):

```
Create FileWriter
Create BufferedWriter with FileWriter
Start your while loop and loop through your groups
  Do your loops, get your user's input
  Write out the users input using the BufferedWriter
end while loop
Close the BufferedWriter (preferably done in a finally block).
```

As an aside, next time, include all pertinent information with your question, including your use of loops. We sometimes are terrible at guessing at code not shown or information not provided.

Answer (score 1):

With the information given I can only suggest opening the file in append mode.

Insted of:

```
FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(name + ".txt");
```

Use:

```
FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(name + ".txt", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code only writes one line, in fact not even that, just a string without a line terminator. It writes it to a file which is newly created every time this code executes. No basis is apparent for your expectation that there will be more data in the file.

You may have intended to open the file in 'append' mode, or to keep the file open and write multiple times to it before closing.